# Can't get java.util.logging to work with app launched via JNLP

Tags: java, jnlp, java.util.logging

For debugging purposes, I would like my app to log to a java.util.logging.SocketHandler. Here's, my configuration file:

```
handlers = java.util.logging.SocketHandler
.level = WARNING
java.util.logging.SocketHandler.level = ALL
java.util.logging.SocketHandler.formatter = java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter
java.util.logging.SocketHandler.host = localhost
java.util.logging.SocketHandler.port = 10101
com.mycompany.level = ALL
```

This logging configuration file is bundled with the app's jar and read from main. When I launch the app standalone, the logging works as expected. I see log statements streaming to localhost:10101. However, when i launch the app via JNLP is see no logging. Here's my JNLP configuration file:

```
<jnlp spec="1.0+" codebase="http://mycompany.com" href="myapp.jnlp">
  <information>
    <title>My App</title>
    <vendor>My Company</vendor>
    <offline-allowed/>
  </information>
  <security>
      <all-permissions/>
  </security>
  <resources>
    <j2se version="1.6+"/>
    <jar href="myapp.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <application-desc main-class="com.mycompany.Main"/>
</jnlp>
```

I have not found any information nor do I see any reason why this shouldn't work. Could someone please help make this work? Or suggest another (maybe better?) way to capture logging from an app launched via JNLP.

Comment: You might try setting the properties in the JNLP.  E.G. `<property name="key" value="overwritten"/> ` according to [the JNLP description](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html#resources).

Comment: @andrew I'm not sure which properties specifically you're suggesting I define in the JNLP. But if you're referring to "java.util.logging.config.file", I've already tried this and no luck :(

Comment: No I meant each of the properties.  E.G. `<property name=".level" value="WARNING"/>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I figured it out. It turns out my problem was how I was loading the logging properties file as a resource. I was using:

```
ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream("/com/mycompany/logging.properties");
```

But I should have used:

```
Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/com/mycompany/logging.properties");
```